# How can I use the IronLanguages' Tools without buying VS?

Tags: visual-studio, ironpython, ironruby

IronRuby's "Tools" pack looks like a really attractive IDE to me, except for the fact that I need to buy Visual Studio to use it.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3):

From the IronRuby CodePlex download page:

> The tools also work with the free [Visual Studio 2010 Integrated Shell](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=8e5aa7b6-8436-43f0-b778-00c3bca733d3&displaylang=enhttp://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=8e5aa7b6-8436-43f0-b778-00c3bca733d3&displaylang=en).

I have no idea how *well* it works...

Comment: It works very well. It is the correct way to use extensions if you do not have a pro license.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the VS 2010 Express Editions and then download the IronPython or IronRuby tools as addon.